# Simple publisher in rosmatlab

Tags: ros, rosmatlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to write a simple publisher using [rosmatlab](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/rosmatlab), rosmatlab is installed perfectly and I can access ros-api (limited functionality) in the matlab command window, however I am having hard time advertising a topic, here's the matlab script:

```
argc=1;
argv='';
ros.init(argc,argv,'mat_ros');
P = ros.Publisher;
topic_name = 'chatter';
msg_type = 'std_msgs.String';
queue_size = 1000;
P.advertise(topic_name,'std_msgs.String',1000);
```

**Error:**

```
Error using internal
[ROS] Publisher.advertise: unknown datatype 'std_msgs.String'

Error in ros.Publisher/advertise (line 38)
        result = internal(obj, 'advertise', topic, datatype,
        varargin{:});
```

I have tried to change the datatype to 'String', 'string','ros_string' etc etc but still I am getting the same error. If I pass second arguments without the quotes, then I get this:

```
P.advertise(topic_name, std_msgs.String,1000);

Error using internal
[ROS] Publisher.advertise: need a datatype as 2nd argument

Error in ros.Publisher/advertise (line 38)
        result = internal(obj, 'advertise', topic, datatype,
        varargin{:});
```

Any idea how can I get rid of this data-type error ? If someone can please share a simple publisher/subscriber script for rosmatlab ? as the wiki page of rosmatlab only has the installation instructions and no sample code.

Thanks

Regards,

Usama

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72292/simple-publisher-in-rosmatlab/) by [uyaseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5164/uyaseen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally figured out that ***Message types*** have to be specified using the 'package/Message' syntax i.e 'std_msgs/String'. All message packages beside std_msgs have to be imported before the first usage by just entering the package name without arguments (e.g. geometry_msgs, sensor_msgs, ...).

---

Originally posted by [uyaseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/5164/uyaseen/) with karma: 78 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ram99](https://answers.ros.org/users/9696/ram99/) on 2013-12-08**:
Hi, How did you figure out the Matlab commands in rosmatlab. I am using rosmatlab package aswell. I want to publish some String message. But I couldnot find any proper Documentation for it.Can you help me.

**Comment by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) on 2013-12-08**:
@Ram99 - this is a Q&A site, not a forum. Please create a new question rather than asking in the comments of an old one.